# Compare matrices and output the difference

Tags: r, matrix

I want to compare two matrices

```
  A B C
A 1 1 0
B 0 1 -1
C 1 0 0
  A B C
A 1 -1 0
B 0 -1 -1
C 1 0 1
```

So that output should be

```
  A B C
A 0 -1 0
B 0 -1 0
C 0 0 1
```

Values for which `matrix 1 == matrix 2` will be `0` and for which `matrix1 != matrix2` the value of `matrix2` will be assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a "term by term" comparison with `mat1==mat2` and then put the number you want according to the result: 
if `mat1` and `mat2` are your matrices:

```
> ifelse(mat1==mat2, 0, mat2)
   #   A  B C
   # A 0 -1 0
   # B 0 -1 0
   # C 0  0 1
```

**EDIT based on the comments**
If you also want to know which percentage of values were not equal, you can do:

```
eq <- mat1==mat2 # avoid to later compute this twice
ifelse(eq, 0, mat2) # get the desired matrix
round(sum(!eq)/length(eq)*100, 2) # get the percentage of non equal values
#[1] 33.33
```

Comment: In row A and B of the resulting matrix, the value is -1 because in 'mat2' the value was changed by '-1'. Whereas, in row C the last value should be '1' not '-1' because the corresponding value in mat1 (0) is replaced by (1) in mat2.

Comment: Is it possible to apply some scoring function on this. Some function which represents how much different the compared matrices are? for example a percentage or so..

Comment: I don't think this is the solution. Let me explain again. For example in above example there were total 3 replacements. so among 9 values of M1 and M2 3 values has been changed in resulting matrix, so percentage of change will be 33.33%. I mean a calculation like this.

Comment: @user3253470 so probably `sum(mat1!=mat2)/length(mat2)*100`

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me how I should deal the cases where dimension of matrices to compared are not same? In such cases I am getting "non-conformable arrays" error message

Comment: @user3253470 how can you check if 2 matrices are the same "element-wise" if they haven't the same dimension: how do you make the element "match" ? (ie how do you know which element to use for your comparison?)

Comment: @user3253470 it not a good practice to extend your problem statement in the same question. If you think CathG answer solves your problem you should accept it and ask your another question separately.

Comment: @Cath Can you please suggest the answer for this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420909/compare-matrices-to-find-the-differences]