# Compare matrices to find the differences

Tags: r, matrix, comparison, difference

I have 2 matrices, I want to compare them (row.name wise) to find the difference.

```
> head(N1)
              Total_Degree Transitivity Betweenness Closeness_All
2410016O06RIK            1          NaN     0.00000  0.0003124024
AGO1                     4    0.1666667    37.00000  0.0003133814
APEX1                    4    0.6666667     4.00000  0.0003144654
ATR                      4    0.1666667    19.50000  0.0003128911
CASP3                   24    0.0000000   806.00000  0.0002980626
CCND2                    4    0.3333333    97.33333  0.0003132832

head(N2)
              Total_Degree Transitivity Betweenness Closeness_All
2410016O06RIK            1          NaN         0.0  2.279982e-04
ADI1                     1          NaN         0.0  1.728877e-05
AGO1                     3    0.0000000        40.0  2.284670e-04
AIRN                     1          NaN         0.0  1.721733e-05
APEX1                    3    0.6666667         2.0  2.288330e-04
ATR                      3    0.3333333        19.5  2.281542e-04
```

Many of the rows.name in N1 do exist in N2, I want to compare them and write the difference in a new matrix. Those which are unique to N1 or N2 should be mentioned that they either belong to N1 or N2.

I am not sure which is the best criteria to calculate the difference, what I can think of, is a simple addition of all values of a row in N1 and subtract that value from additive value of corresponding row in N2.

For example output should be:

```
> head(Compared)
                       Comparison Unique 
    2410016O06RIK        0.0002     Common
    AGO1                 -1.83      Common
    APEX1                 2.24      Common
    ATR                  0.0034     Common
    CASP3               830.00029   N1
    ADI1                1.0007288   N2
```

Here for row.name = `2410016O06RIK`, all values from N1 and N2 were added and then `N1-N2` was written in `Comparison` column, as this row was common in both matrices so `common` was written in `Unique` column.

Comment: Could you provide code to reproduce the data? For uniqueness I would go with inner and left/right joins by row.name, then simply rbind three resulting data.frames, and for the difference maybe `all.equal()` would do the job? You need to specify what you mean by a "difference".

Comment: @M.D I'm reading the text files here, I don't know how I can provide you the data. From difference I mean "let's consider that row.names are different person and we have their income from different sources in different columns. We calculate their overall income (adding all values of a row) in 2 time points (N1 and N2) and we want to find out the person whose income has drastically changed across these time points (by subtracting N1 - N2)".

Comment: That is a draft of solution using data.table package, if you are not familiar with it I will try to rewrite it without it: (here was the code, but I will post it as a solution for readability).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to go in base R, with `rowSums` and `merge`:

***If `N1` and `N2` are data.frames:***

```
# compute the row sums and merge N1 and N2
N1$rs <- rowSums(N1, na.rm=TRUE)
N2$rs <- rowSums(N2, na.rm=TRUE)
comp <- merge(N1[, "rs", drop=FALSE], N2[, "rs", drop=FALSE], by="row.names", all=TRUE)

# then compare the row sums and the variable "locations"
comp$Unique <- with(comp, c("N1", "N2", "common")[(!is.na(rs.x)) + 2*(!is.na(rs.y))])
comp$Comparison <- with(comp, rs.x-rs.y)

# keep only the variable you need:
comp <- comp[, c(1, 5, 4)]
```

***If `N1` and `N2` are matrices:***

```
# compute the row sums and merge N1 and N2
rs1 <- rowSums(N1, na.rm=TRUE)
rs2 <- rowSums(N2, na.rm=TRUE)
comp <- merge(N1, N2, by="row.names", all=TRUE)

# then compare the row sums and the variable "locations"
comp$Unique <- with(comp, c("N1", "N2", "common")[as.numeric(!is.na(Total_Degree.x)) + 2*as.numeric(!is.na(Total_Degree.y))])
comp$Comparison <- with(merge(as.data.frame(rs1), as.data.frame(rs2), all=TRUE, by="row.names"), rs1-rs2)

# keep only the variable you need:
comp <- comp[, c("Row.names", "Comparison", "Unique")]
```

***output of both methods:***

```
comp
#      Row.names    Comparison Unique
#1 2410016O06RIK  0.0000844042 common
#2          ADI1            NA     N2
#3          AGO1 -1.8332483856 common
#4          AIRN            NA     N2
#5         APEX1  3.0000856324 common
#6           ATR  0.8334181369 common
#7         CASP3            NA     N1
#8         CCND2            NA     N1
```

Comment: `comp <- merge(N1[, "rs", drop=FALSE], N2[, "rs", drop=FALSE], by="row.names", all=TRUE)` This command results in: **Error in N1[, "rs", drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions**. Can you tell me how I can solve it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think this is the right way to compare the matrices/data.frames to get the differences or there are other methods out there? Secondly, can you guide me how can I provide the data for future questions? Thanks indeed.

Comment: @user3253470, easiest question : you can either make a small reproducible example of dummy data or use `dput` on a part of your data to give us the structure. For your other question, I guess it depends on what kind of information you are after. Does the difference of rowSums make sense ? do you need a variable-wise difference ? something else ? I'd say it is up to what you need actually...

Comment: Regarding the comparison, your columns seem to be from completely different ranges/distributions, so you definitely cannot compare them as you want to. Maybe some normalisation and then sums/differences?

Comment: @Cath Can you help me with UPDATE section of this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35484595/data-frame-merge-and-selection-of-values-which-are-common-in-2-data-frames]

Comment: @user3253470 I've commented under PierreLafortune's post, sorry I didn't realise it wasn't the OP that pinged me

Answer (score 2):

That is a part of the solution, in `res` you have a `data.table` to work with for the difference part:

```
require(data.table)
require(dplyr)

set.seed(2016)
dt1 <- data.table(V1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), V2 = rnorm(4))
dt2 <- data.table(V1 = c("c", "d", "e", "f"), V2 = rnorm(4))

# common <- merge(dt1, dt2, by = "V1")[, Unique := "Common"]
# unique1 <- dt1[V1 %nin% dt2[, V1], ][, Unique := "N1"]
# unique2 <- dt2[V1 %nin% dt1[, V1], ][, Unique := "N2"]
# res <- rbind(common, unique1, unique2, fill = TRUE)
```

Small update after @Cath answer, just for clarity.

```
allMerged <- merge(dt1, dt2, by = "V1", all = TRUE) %>%
  .[, RowSum := rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = grep("V2", names(.))] %>%
  .[, Unique := ((is.na(V2.x) + 2*is.na(V2.y)))]

print(allMerged)
```

Comment: ah-ah, I didn't know why (oh why) I had to put `as.numeric` on my `is.na` test when I really didn't want too, but it was just a matter of being careful the first `!` didn't negate the whole "sentence" :-)

Comment: I would be carefull there, as you need to wrap every `(!is.na(V2.x))` in braces, if not you will end with logical vector of TRUE/FALSEs. Without `!` it is not the case, which is easier I think.

Comment: though without `!`, you don't really get the "correct" information (putting `2*is.na(V2.x) + is.na(V2.y)` would get you half there but you'll still have `0` for common values...)

Comment: @Cath, and this 0 is distinct only for the common values, which looks okay for me - you can then recode this hovewer you want.

Comment: @M.D Can you help me with UPDATE section of this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35484595/data-frame-merge-and-selection-of-values-which-are-common-in-2-data-frames]

Comment: @user3253470, why not ask in the original question? See the `stats::aggregate`, `dplyr::summarise` or the `data.table` `by` syntax.